# Promise inside forEach loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a API call to update a record in a loop. I want to have a promise around API call so that the next iteration is not called until the first is finished. How can I achieve this?

I have tried this but this gives an error "Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function"

```
async saveMyData(){
  this.elements.forEach(element => {
        await this.$refs.DM.saveInternalData(element)
  })
}
```

Comment: The arrow function you pass to `forEach` is a different function to `saveMyData`!

Comment: You can't use `await` inside a `forEach` callback: you need to use the good old `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an `async` function in a loop, you can do:

```
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
  await foo();
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can do:
await Promise.all(this.elements.map(this.$refs.DM.saveInternalData))